# A question about $S(n)=S(m) \Rightarrow n=m$, S being the successor function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, peano-axioms

In Naive Set Theory, Halmos proves that $S(n)=S(m) \Rightarrow n=m$ [in this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvNQy.png):

> We are now ready to prove $(V)$.  Suppose indeed that $n$ and $m$ are natural numbers and that $n^+ = m^+$.  Since $n\in n^{+}$, it follows that $n\in m^{+}$, and hence that either $n\in m$ or $n=m$.  Similarly, $m\in n$ or $m=n$.  If $n\ne m$, then we must have $n\in m$ and $m\in n$.  Since, by (ii), $n$ is transitive, it follows that $n\in n$.  Since, however, $n\subset n$, this contradicts (i), and the proof is complete.

Where (i) and (ii) are [these:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEkfX.png) (i) *no natural number is a subset of any of its elements*, and (ii) *every element of a natural number is a subset of it*. I don't understand why you need to use (i). If we have $n\in m$ then $n \subset m$ follows by (ii), right? And by $m\in n$ we likewise get $m \subset n$. Therefore $n=m$ and we have a contradiction. What am I missing here? He sets it up like (i) is necessary for the proof.

Comment: You might want to type out $(i)$ and $(ii)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's formalize this here :

(i) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \not\in n$

(ii) $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, m \in n \implies m \subset n$

Let $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such as $S(m) = S(n)$.

According to the proof linked in the post, we have :

$$(m = n \lor m \in n) \ \land \ (m = n \lor n \in m)$$

which is equivalent to :

$$ (m = n) \ \lor \ (m \in n \land n \in m)$$

By using (ii), we have the implication :

$$ (m \in n \land n \in m) \implies (m \subset n \land n \subset m) \implies (m = n) $$

So this shows that in any case, $m = n$. The answer to your question is : yes, we can proove that $S$ is injective without using (i).